# mysql form meta data

Tags: mysql, sql

```
select a.customer_id from 
(
    select customer_id, username, referral_id from customer
) a,
(
    select username as new from customer where referral_id = a.customer_id
) b
```

My table schema has meta data so trying to fetch and use it in another query but getting error unknown column a.customer_id in where clause. How can I write the above query in correct manner

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have written an interesting query.  I think this is what you want:

```
select c.customer_id
from customer c join
     customer cr
     on c.customer_id = cr.referral_id;
```

Your query shows some knowledge of SQL, and yet you don't seem to understand one of the most basic and key concepts, joins.  In any case, you don't need subqueries for this.  And you want to put join conditions into an `on` clause.  And you want to use explicit join syntax.  You should study up on joins.